# Displaying a data-bound StackPanel inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, stackpanel

I have objects I'm databinding to a ListBox in WPF. Here's what the end result should look like:

```
-------------------------------
| Name    | Opt1    |  Value1 |
|         | Opt2    |  Value2 |
|         | Opt3    |  Value3 |
|         | Opt4    |  Value4 |
-------------------------------
```

Essentially i've got a DataTemplate for the overall variable, and then the Opt/Value combo has it's own DataTemplate. I'm trying to display the list of values as simply as possible.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Identifier.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
<ListView Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The binding for Values is currently only a `<Grid>` with 2 `<Label>`'s and ListView has a lot of features I dont watch, such as the border styling, selections, and such, when all I really want is to be able to databind using a List.

I've tried to databind the items to a stackpanel but couldn't get it to work in XAML. I suppose another solution is to do what I'm doing, and rewrite the `<Style>` for ListView. Any suggestions on the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly sounds like something you can do with a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx), or an ItemsControl if you do not want them to be selectable.  We can also make use of the [IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) attached property to keep our columns formatted and even.  Also, take a look at the Inheritance Higharchy at the bottom of the ListBox link, it should help you determine which type of list you need for different scenarios.

Try something like this:

```
<DockPanel>
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Identifier.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}"
           Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="OptionColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ValueColumn" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Option}" />
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: ItemsControl was exactly what I needed. Thanks.