# Listbox scrollbar thumb changes size when content is variable height

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemscontrol

I have a ListBox with many objects displayed, each of which can be a variable height, based on the number of values each object has. [See my previous question that was answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957771/displaying-a-data-bound-stackpanel-inside-a-datatemplate)

Many objects are 5-lines high, while others are 1. The scroll bar in the ListBox does not appear to like this, probably due to the virtualization. While you scroll through, **the thumb on the scroll bar will change its size**, based on how many items are actually fitting into the box at that current moment. This makes the thumb very big at times, and very small at other times.

Since this ListBox is also contained within a TabControl, when you switch from one tab to another, the ListBox will often scroll to a different section when you return to it.

Any ideas how to resolve an issue like this?

**Additional Info:**
Disabling virtualization does fix the scrolling problem, although at the cost of a slower initial display. However, resizing the ListBox with the content inside causes some heavy lag when resizing horizontally (vertical is fine), which I'm assuming is due to my template's width changing and requiring a redraw on every element:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xmlset:Variable}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Margin="2,2,0,2"  Text="{Binding Path=Identifier.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Margin="2,2,0,2" Text="{Binding Path=Optimization, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBox Margin="0,2,0,2" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is drawing borders around the edges of the fields to make a visual grouping, where val will stretch to the content size. The listbox also has HorizontalContentAlignmment = Stretch to ensure this looks correct.

```
-------------------
- var - opt - val -
-     -------------
-     - opt - val -
-     -------------
-     - opt - val -
-------------------
```

*note: if this needs to be asked in a different question, tell me and i'll seperate the questions*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not switch off any size restrictions on the ListBox itself, let it size to contents and wrap it into a ScrollViewer, setting a proper size for the latter?

The markup should look like the following:

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="640px" Height="480px">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--Visualization of a list item-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I saw no thumb size changings during scrolling if it was implemented this way.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if the scroll viewer is going to fill a window? This does fix the thumb size problem, however resizing the window is very, very slow due to automatic widths and heights.

Comment: Yes, it is. ScrollViewer is made to fill the parent control just as any other control, like this.

<Window Width="640" Height="480">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>

And thumb is still ok.
Which resizing performanse do you mean? In my test program running on an average laptop with a list of 200 items resizing of window and all of it's contents looks instant.

Comment: I'm having issues with horizontal scrolling, due to the DataTemplate redrawing on every element when stretching. I'm creating the ListBox programmatically in a TabItem. See the updated question. Would this always be a drawback when HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch without virtualization?

Comment: If the reason of lag is really calculation of width, then try this. Handle resize event of the ListBox programmatically, inside of the handler get the actual width, beforehand set automatically because of stretch alignment, turn stretch alignment off and set that width explicitly.

Comment: Important addition: placing ListBox inside a ScrollViewer wrapper will kill the performance in case of virtualizing ListBox. Reason of such degradation is simple: ScrollViewer will enforce its child content to render first, so having hundreds and thousands of items in the ListBox will be a long pause for many seconds.

Answer (score 7):

Set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` on the ListBox, this will disable what's called "logical scrolling", which does scrolling based on item count instead of height ("physical scrolling").

Comment: This also disables virtualization, making it act the same as a ListBox in a ScrollViewer

Comment: You'll have to make a custom implementation to get around this; the normal physical scrolling requires the total computed height. (the scroll bar thumb size is based on the currently visible height relative to the total)

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but HOW do you set this on a listbox? I can wrap my listbox in a scrollviewer, but that breaks the scroll wheel, so I need to do this...

Comment: It was a stupid question :) `<ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`

Answer (score 0):

Disable virtualization or make the items in your ListBox all of equal height. If you've got less than 100 items or so, you can live without the virtualization.

Comment: I have around 200 items. I tried disabling virtualization by making the ItemsPanelTemplate a StackPanel, which i see loads slower initially but then scrolls faster. However, the scrollbar still constantly changes size, so this doesn't fix the issue. I'd rather not change the item size if I don't have to, but it's starting to look like I might.