# Styling listbox in WPF in Blend

Tags: wpf, listbox, styling, blend

Can you link me to tutorials for styling listbox in Blend 4? I only need to change the colours of listbox parts and mouse over and selected states.

I know this is pretty popular and already asked question, but all answers that link to tutorials are for Blend version 3 or 4beta.

Comment: Not to be harsh, but StackO shouldn't be used as a substitute for a thorough web search.

Comment: I've searched, as I said, it's all for old versions and for some reasons it's totally different. It might be in some book too, someone could give a ref.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this video tutorial, [Customizing the Look of a Listbox in Expression Blend](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd334538), with blend 2 but still a good point to start with.

Comment: It's a little bit different than what I need. Anyways, do you know how to change height of the thumb without affecting decreas and increase repeat buttons?

Comment: ...maybe this answer addressing the same issue can give you a further hint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976586/listbox-scrollbar-thumb-changes-size-when-content-is-variable-height

Comment: It sounds like a solution, but it didn't work. Perhaps it's not possible, I didn't see anywhere a smaller size thumb than the default one.